# How can I change the font size of the number in minted environment?

Tags: fontsize, minted, line-numbering

How can I change the font size of the number in minted environment?
The font can be modified with `fontsize` parameter, but the number on the left side is not affected with it.

[image]
[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm,
               fontsize=\tiny]{csharp}
  string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
  /*
  Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
  of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
  circle of diameter $d$.
  */
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\theFancyVerbLine` should be redefined to control the line number style.

```
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\huge \oldstylenums{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}
```

Comment: How does this affect line number referencing?

Comment: @Werner `fancyvrb` redefines `\refstepcounter` for its purposes so that it essentially uses `\arabic{FancyVerbLine}` for defining `\@currentlabel`, rather than `\theFancyVerbLine` (see lines 1076–1080). So redefining `\theFancyVerbLine` is OK.