# How do I change the style of the minted line numbers with line skips?

Tags: minted

I'm using `minted` to show pieces of code in my document. Some of the code has [skipped line numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380013/skip-line-numbers-and-resume-from-specific-number-in-minted). The resulting problem is that listings with skipped line numbers have different line number formatting than the ones without.

[image: Example with skipped lines]

The `minted` documentation and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132849/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-the-number-in-minted-environment) StackExchange question shows a way to modify the `theFancyVerbLine` command to change the formatting. However that won't effect the listings with line skips.

[image: Renewed the FanceVerb environment]

I tried combining the two approaches but that would duplicate the line numbers. What do I miss from the `minted` documentation?

Thanks in advance.

---

Minimal working example:

```
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes }
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \begin{minted}[linenos]{py}
import bar from foo

print("Hello %s!" % "World")
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
    \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=2
        \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{125}\ldots
    \else
    \arabic{FancyVerbLine}%
    \fi
    }
    \begin{minted}[linenos]{py}
import deep_thought as dt

print("The answer is %s!" % dt.getAnswerTo("everything"))
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required modification is to replace `\arabic{FancyVerbLine}` in the second listing with the definition above, i.e., `\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}`.

Furthermore you can color the dots and make them vertical.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \begin{minted}[linenos]{py}
import bar from foo

print("Hello %s!" % "World")
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
    \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=2
        \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{125}\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}\vdots
    \else
    \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}%
    \fi
    }
    \begin{minted}[linenos]{py}
import bar from foo

print("Goodbye %s!" % "World")
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]